# Default value of DateTime is not working as expected

Tags: c#, datetime, default-value

I have a class with DateTime and DateTime? variables,"if (value != defaultValue)" should fail and the control should not go inside. but then here in my case it is executing.
(value != defaultValue) is not working. what can I replace the code with.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Reflection;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DateClass v = new DateClass();
            v.Date1 = default;
            v.Date1 = default;          

            foreach (PropertyInfo pi in v.GetType().GetProperties())
            {
                var type = pi.PropertyType;
                var value = pi.GetValue(v);
                var defaultValue = GetDefault(type);

                if (value != defaultValue)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("not equal");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("equal");

                }
            }

        }

        public static object GetDefault(Type type)
        {
            if (type.IsValueType)
            {
                var k = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
                return k;
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    public class DateClass
    {
        public DateTime Date1
        {
            get; set;
        }
        public DateTime? Date2
        {
            get; set;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the *compile-time* type of `PropertyInfo.GetValue` is `object`... which means that basically you're boxing the `DateTime`, and then comparing two different references, with a reference comparison.

Personally I'd say that a field with a value of `DateTime.MinValue` (aka `default(DateTime)` is still non-null (as is an `int` field with a value of 0, for example), and that you should either change the name of the method or only exclude genuine null values. However, if you *do* want to down this route, I'd change your condition to just

```cs
if (!Equals(value, defaultValue))
```

That will perform a *value* equality check, which is what you want.